# How to get one uniform colorbar and color scale for multiple GeoPandas plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, colorbar, imshow

I have 3 geopandas plots and I want to have one colorbar and the same (color) limits for all three plots.

This is my code for the plots:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[1].axis('off')
ax[2].axis('off')

result.plot(column = '2015', ax=ax[0], cmap = 'viridis', edgecolor="Black", linewidth=0.2, figsize=(3,3))
result.plot(column = '2016', ax=ax[1], cmap = 'viridis' , edgecolor="Black", linewidth=0.2, figsize=(3,3))
result.plot(column = '2017', ax=ax[2], cmap = 'viridis' ,  edgecolor="Black", linewidth=0.2, figsize=(3,3))
```

and this is my current plot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctV7X.png)

any help would be massively appreciated.

I have tried using the fig.colorbar() with a variety of different arguments.
I have got both Attribute errors and type errors.

I also tried to use the imshow() function however get an Attribute error then too.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `vmin` and `vmax`?

Comment: @Sheldon yes there still is no colorbar though

Comment: Did you pass these arguments into the Geopandas' `plot` function?

Comment: @Sheldon yes I have now written this `result.plot(column = '2015', ax=ax[0], cmap = 'viridis', edgecolor="Black", linewidth=0.2, vmin=0, vmax=506)` . This fixes the second issue but the `fig.colorbar()` function is still erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have access to your data, I create an example of my own with the dataset provided [here](https://github.com/Automating-GIS-processes/Lesson-2-Geo-DataFrames/raw/master/data/Data.zip).

I first load the data:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fp = "/path_to_my_data/DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp"
data = gpd.read_file(fp)
```

Column `ID_NO` contains floats, ranging from 154760.0 to 184017.0.
I create a new column for the sake of the exercise:

```
data['ID_NO_2'] = data['ID_NO'] + 12000
```

Then I compute the `vmin` and `vmax`:

```
custom_vmin = min(data['ID_NO'].min(),data['ID_NO_2'].min())
custom_vmax = max(data['ID_NO'].max(),data['ID_NO_2'].max())
```

`custom_vmin` is 154760.0, `custom_vmax` is 196017.0 (which is consistent with 184017.0 + 12000.0).

The only thing left to do is specify the `vmin` and `vmax` in `plot`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[1].axis('off')


data.plot( column = 'ID_NO', ax=ax[0], cmap = 'viridis', edgecolor="Black", linewidth=0.2, figsize=(3,3), vmin=custom_vmin,  vmax= custom_vmax, legend=True)
data.plot(column = 'ID_NO_2', ax=ax[1], cmap = 'viridis' , edgecolor="Black", linewidth=0.2, figsize=(3,3),  vmin=custom_vmin,  vmax= custom_vmax,legend=True)
```

Note the argument `legend=True` in both `plot` functions.
This yields:

[image]

Note that both colormaps are identical, which is expected, since I use the same `vmin` and `vmax` in both `plot` functions, but of course the maps themselves are different.

Since you only want a single colorbar in your final image, then you may simply specify `legend=True` in the last `plot` function:

[image]